# Rewriting static resource requests with NGINX to subfolders

Tags: html, nginx

I apologize in advance as this may be a bit of a beginner question. But here is the situation:

## Background

I have a static bundle that looks something like this:

```
index.html
assets/
├── image1.png
└── image2.png
```

Inside `index.html`, I have image tags that look like this:

```
<img src="/assets/image1.png" />
```

So when I host a static server locally on port `8000`, and I go to `localhost:8000`, the browser makes a request to `http://localhost:8000/assets/image1.png` and everything works fine.

## Problem

My client is actually using NGINX to point `http://example.com/portal` to the static bundle. Meaning that typing `http://example.com/portal` in the browser would lead you to seeing the `index.html` page.

He tells me that I need to put a `/portal` prefix for all my static assets or else it wouldn't work. That means my `img` tags need to look like this instead of the above:

```
<img src="/portal/assets/image1.png" />
```

If I don't do that, he says the browser ends up requesting `http://example.com/assets/image1.png` instead of `http://example.com/portal/assets/image1.png`.

This screws things up for me because I have to twist the framework I'm using in order to accommodate this. It means I have to write some extra scripts for dev and build, which is annoying and pollutes the repo.

Is there something wrong with his NGINX configuration? Or do I really have to append a `/portal` prefix for all the links or maybe something is wrong with his NGINX configuration?

I do not have access to his NGINX configuration and I also don't have much experience with NGINX either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple enough to use a base tag

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp.

You will change your `index.html` and below in head tag

```
<head>
<base href="/portal/">
</head>
```

and you will change your links to be relative links instead of absolute. So below

```
<img src="/assets/image1.png" />
```

Should change to

```
<img src="assets/image1.png" />
```

And now you will be able to deploy the static files to `/portal` on NGINX